# What happened to voiced velar fricative [ɣ] and velar approximant [ɰ] in English language?

Tags: speech, old-english, phonetics

The voiced velar fricative is a type of consonantal sound, used in various spoken languages.

Wikipedia says that it is not found in English today, but did exist in Old English.<sup>1</sup>

Why did this sound disappear? What happened in the history?

Some other Germanic languages still have that. Might it still exist in some dialects or casual speech in English?

---

Some relevant details<sup>1</sup>:

> The symbol ɣ is also sometimes used to represent the velar approximant, though that is more accurately written with the lowering diacritic: [ɣ̞] or [ɣ˕]. The IPA also provides a dedicated symbol for a velar approximant, [ɰ], though there can be stylistic reasons to not use it in phonetic transcription

Examples from other languages<sup>1</sup>:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

<sub>1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_fricative</sub>

Comment: According to [an electronic equivalent of *Introduction to Old English*, 3rd edition](http://www.wmich.edu/medieval/resources/IOE/pronunciation.html), the sound became /w/ in Middle English. They provide no more information than that, however.

Comment: Can't edit the comment any more. But see section 2.1.2, list item 7, on that page.

Comment: What happened to it? It died out during the shifts from Old to Early Modern English; it was never more than an allophone of /h/, and it now appears (but does not sound) only in some places where (or wear) a GH appears in spelling. As in, for instance, the words _through_ or _enough_. Sort of a ghost.

Comment: @JohnLawler would that explain why an archaic spelling of *enough* is *enow*?

Comment: @Matt: Simplifying greatly, the OED says that the plural forms in Old English ended with a vowel after the 'g/h', and because of the phonetics of the sound change, this meant that the singular forms in Old English eventually became *enough*, while the plural forms in Old English eventually became *enow*. This distinction between *enough* in the singular and *enow* in the plural persisted into Early Modern English. (I never realized that *enow* and *enough* were different.)

Comment: Woo! Cool! *files away linguistics masquerading as trivia*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Old English, /ɣ/ is a phoneme, but the [ɣ] allophone occurred only in a rather specific condition: when word-medially, though not when in gemination, directly after nasals, or directly before a front unrounded vowel or palatal glide.

The word *dagas* ‘days’ (nom./acc. plural), for example, would have been pronounced something like [dɑɣɑs]. *fugol* ‘bird’ (nom. singular) would have been something like [fuɣol].

OE [ɣ] descends from Proto-Germanic /ɣ/, which had a much more widespread distribution. See Richard Hogg's (1992) [Grammar of Old English](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BVlXG_-y4uQC), volume 1, §2.56, for more detail and references.

In Middle English, [ɣ] became vocalized. If it followed a front vowel, it became an instance of /j/, and if it followed a back vowel, it became an instance of /w/. In both cases it went on to form new diphthongs, as in *fowl*, from *fugol*. See p117 of [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=w-BcAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117). At that point there is no longer a /ɣ/ phoneme, or even any allophones (though some do develop later in varieties of English, as David Garner points out).

Answer (score 2):

The voiced velar fricative /ɣ/ does exist in Liverpool speech, but I'm fairly sure it's a more recent development of intervocalic /g/.  I haven't managed to figure out exactly when /g/ does and doesn't change to /ɣ/, but here are two examples.  1. The town-name Maghull [stressed on the second syllable] is pronounced /məˈɣʊɫ/.  2. If you watch just about any episode of Red Dwarf [UK version], you'll hear Dave Lister call Arnold Rimmer a smeghead /ˈsmɛɣɛd/.